# How can I read very large file (Say 4GB) efficiently in JAVA with memory capacity capped at say 500MB

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

In a interview I was asked to calculate mean of data that is stored in very large file. I couldn't think of effective solution other than reading file through Scanner and read line by line and keeping global counter and mean.
Interviewer wasn't impressed with solution

Comment: Real solution: don't bother, just read it, JVM will handle it the most efficent way for you - that's why you use such a language, not "C". :-)

Comment: No need to keep a count, just calculate a [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average).

Comment: @azurefrog Correct me if I'm wrong. For moving average we need total number of point processed and cumulative average till that point

Comment: See - the question is legit, but the intend is not an "answer" in terms of code. Its purpose is to figure out whether you are aware what "Java" (or any other kind-of-framework-language) would do for you, or if you are the kind of "Reinvent-the-wheel-everytime"-developer.

Comment: Are you sure you weren't asked to calculate the *median*?

Comment: What does it mean to "keep a global counter and mean"? I don't know what keeping the mean signifies in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the interviewer was looking for a solution involving reading in large blocks of the file and then processing in memory. There are mechanisms in Java to read large blocks as `byte[]` or `char[]` and then process via scanner in memory. Ask if you want more detail on how to achieve this.

There's a good chance that the interviewer was wrong and you were right. Modern O/S and JVM are quite good at interpreting what you are doing and reading ahead. While I haven't tested it there's a possibility that trying to optimise the read will be counter-productive.